# HAProxy still return 502 after 120seconds

Tags: http, haproxy

I have HAProxy configured that will forward my http requests to various services on internal ports.

One of this service may take some minutes to elaborate an answer, but after 120s HAProxy will still return a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

I have tried to set higher timeouts without any success. Here is the `haproxy.cfg` file

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 4096
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    log global

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    option tcplog
    default_backend my_default_backend
    timeout client 10m
    timeout server 10m

    acl is_test_request hdr(host) -i testrequest.mydomain.ext
    use_backend test_timeout if is_test_request

backend test_timeout
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 10m
    server s1 127.0.0.1:8099

listen admin
    bind *:8080
    stats enable
```

Yes, there are repeated `timeout` directives, this is the file after few tests I made.

There are also some other `acl` and `use_backend` but I have trimmed them out.

How can I set an higher timeout for that service?

Update:

This is a sample log line

```
May 22 07:25:52 localhost haproxy[2552]: CLIENT_IP_REDACTED:PORT [22/May/2018:07:23:52.402] http-in test_timeout/s1 0/0/120004 204 SH 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
```

the service listening on port `8099` was waiting 180seconds to send a response, but after 120 haproxy sent back a

```
502 Bad Gateway

The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
```

Comment: You need to check the HAProxy logs and show us an entry for the failed request.  When a timeout fires, HAProxy should return `504 Gateway Timeout`.  `502 Bad Gateway` should mean something else, like an invalid response, and exactly what that is should be coded in the log message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SH` in your log entry tells the story.  This field is called Session State at Disconnection, and is tremendously valuable.  What you logged suggests that you need to look more closely at the web server's configuration and behavior.  The web server itself appears to be closing the connection while HAProxy is waiting for the response.

Here's how I arrived at this conclusion:

> `S`: the TCP session was unexpectedly aborted by the server, or the server explicitly refused it.

We know that the server didn't *refuse* the connection, so we assume the server closed it, and look to the second value.

> `H`: the proxy was waiting for complete, valid response HEADERS from the server (HTTP only).

So, before the proxy had received the `\r\n\r\n` following a set of valid HTTP response headers, the web server unexpectedly closed the connection.

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#8.5

Comment: Thanks a log Michael! I was using NodeJS as underlying service and it has a default 120000ms ( = 2mins) socket timeout by default. 
I was able to disable that timeout and now it works as expected. I was looking to the wrong actor here! 